# Положение карты и списка

Tags: css

В примере "Вывод списка объектов карты" ( https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_list ) список объектов расположен под картой. Как список расположить слева от карты?

Answer (score 2):

Ну как я понял это просто простой `css`.

Вот сам пример с яндекса.

```js
// Группы объектов
var groups = [
        {
            name: "Известные памятники",
            style: "islands#redIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.426472, 30.563022],
                    name: "Монумент &quot;Родина-Мать&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.45351, 30.516489],
                    name: "Памятник &quot;Богдану Хмельницкому&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.454433, 30.529874],
                    name: "Арка Дружбы народов"
                }
            ]},
        {
            name: "Покушайки",
            style: "islands#greenIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.50955, 30.60791],
                    name: "Ресторан &quot;Калинка-Малинка&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.429083, 30.521708],
                    name: "Бар &quot;Сало-бар&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.450843, 30.498271],
                    name: "Абсент-бар &quot;Палата №6&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.454834, 30.516498],
                    name: "Ресторан &quot;Спотыкач&quot;"
                }
            ]},
        {
            name: "Оригинальные музейчики",
            style: "islands#orangeIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.443334, 30.520163],
                    name: "Музей грамзаписи и старинных музыкальных инструментов"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.446977, 30.505269],
                    name: "Музей истории медицины или Анатомический театр"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.452512, 30.530889],
                    name: "Музей воды. Водно-информационный центр"
                }
            ]},
        {
            name: "Красивости",
            style: "islands#blueIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.45987, 30.516174],
                    name: "Замок Ричарда-Львиное сердце"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.445049, 30.528598],
                    name: "&quot;Дом с химерами&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.449156, 30.511809],
                    name: "Дом Рыцаря"
                }
            ]}
    ];

ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {

    // Создание экземпляра карты.
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [50.443705, 30.530946],
            zoom: 14
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        // Контейнер для меню.
        menu = $('<ul class="menu"/>');
        
    for (var i = 0, l = groups.length; i < l; i++) {
        createMenuGroup(groups[i]);
    }

    function createMenuGroup (group) {
        // Пункт меню.
        var menuItem = $('<li><a href="#">' + group.name + '</a></li>'),
        // Коллекция для геообъектов группы.
            collection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(null, { preset: group.style }),
        // Контейнер для подменю.
            submenu = $('<ul class="submenu"/>');

        // Добавляем коллекцию на карту.
        myMap.geoObjects.add(collection);
        // Добавляем подменю.
        menuItem
            .append(submenu)
            // Добавляем пункт в меню.
            .appendTo(menu)
            // По клику удаляем/добавляем коллекцию на карту и скрываем/отображаем подменю.
            .find('a')
            .bind('click', function () {
                if (collection.getParent()) {
                    myMap.geoObjects.remove(collection);
                    submenu.hide();
                } else {
                    myMap.geoObjects.add(collection);
                    submenu.show();
                }
            });
        for (var j = 0, m = group.items.length; j < m; j++) {
            createSubMenu(group.items[j], collection, submenu);
        }
    }

    function createSubMenu (item, collection, submenu) {
        // Пункт подменю.
        var submenuItem = $('<li><a href="#">' + item.name + '</a></li>'),
        // Создаем метку.
            placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(item.center, { balloonContent: item.name });

        // Добавляем метку в коллекцию.
        collection.add(placemark);
        // Добавляем пункт в подменю.
        submenuItem
            .appendTo(submenu)
            // При клике по пункту подменю открываем/закрываем баллун у метки.
            .find('a')
            .bind('click', function () {
                if (!placemark.balloon.isOpen()) {
                    placemark.balloon.open();
                } else {
                    placemark.balloon.close();
                }
                return false;
            });
    }

    // Добавляем меню в тэг BODY.
    menu.appendTo($('body'));
    // Выставляем масштаб карты чтобы были видны все группы.
    myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Примеры. Список объектов карты.</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="groups.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="object_list.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map {
    width: 47%;
    height: 250px;
    float: right;
}
.menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
        .submenu li {
            font-size: 90%;
        }
            /* Оформление меню (конец)*/
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо. С `float` в `css` я тоже пробовал и работает если нет дополнительных элементов на странице. Мне эту карту со списком нужно впихнуть в таблицу. Шаблон страницы сделан таблицей, я его поменять не могу. И получается, например:
`<table border=1 width=95%><tr><td>col1</td><td>col2<br><div id="map"></div></td><td>col3</td></tr></table>`
карта в ячейке, а список выпадает под таблицу.

Comment: @180911 вы тогда пример своего шаблона дайте в вопросе